# JQuery slideToggle not working in content html ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load, toggle

```
$('.slideToggle1').click(function(){
$(this).siblings('.mover1').slideToggle();
});
```

......
In body:

```
<h3 class="slideToggle1" ><img src="images/como/menu/1.png" style="max-width:100%"   alt=""/></h3>
<div class="mover1" style=" display:none;" >
<p><img src="images/como/imagenes/1.png" style="max-width:100%"  alt=""/></p>
</div>
```

Work ok.
........................................................

But if called by ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "xxxxxx/example.php",
  data: "",
   success: function(resp){

        $("#contenedor").html(resp);
   }
```

And resp ajax is:

```
<h3 class="slideToggle1" ><img src="images/como/menu/5.png" style="max-width:100%"   alt=""/></h3>
<div class="mover1" style=" display:none;" >
<p><img src="images/como/imagenes/5.png" style="max-width:100%"  alt=""/></p>
</div>
```

The slideToggle isn't working - can someone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('.slideToggle1').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#contenendor').on('click', '.slideToggle1', function (
```

Event delegation technique as `.slideToggle` doesn't exist and it is dynamically inserted to DOM.

Comment: Thanks, i m use:
$('#contenedor').on('click', '.slideToggle1', function (){
$(this).siblings('.mover1').slideToggle();});